# Drop menu won't close properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two drop menus that I need to close when a user clicks outside of them, or on the other drop menu. I have tried several methods without success and only one works slightly. Currently, the "state" menu will open and close properly (the first time) and then not work correctly the second time. but will work properly the 3rd time, and so on. Not sure what's going on here. Any help would be great!

Here's my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SteveSerrano/rc7fhhhu/6/

HTML:

```
<div class="state_box">
<input type="checkbox" id="state-tgl" onblur="myFunction()">
<label id="state-tgl-label" for="state-tgl"> <span class="collapse_tiny">Choose a state</span>

    <img src="/images/template2014/dropdown-black.svg" style="vertical-align:middle; width:10px;">
</label>
<ul class="state-menu" id="state_drop-menu">
    <li class="option"><a href="http://www.pia.org/CT"><span class="collapse_tiny">Connecticut</span></a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="http://www.pia.org/NH"><span class="collapse_tiny">New Hampshire</span></a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="http://www.pia.org/NJ"><span class="collapse_tiny">New Jersey</span></a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="http://www.pia.org/NY"><span class="collapse_tiny">New   York</span></a>

    </li>
</ul>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="carrier_box">
<input type="checkbox" id="carrier-tgl">
<label id="carrier-tgl-label" for="carrier-tgl"> <span class="collapse_tiny">Select a carrier</span>

    <img src="/images/template2014/dropdown-black.svg" style="vertical-align:middle; width:10px;">
</label>
<ul id="carrier_drop-menu">
    <li><a href="http://www.pia.org/CT"><span class="collapse_tiny">Carrier 1</span><span class="collapse expand_tiny inline">Conn.</span></a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="http://www.pia.org/NH"><span class="collapse_tiny">Carrier 2</span><span class="collapse expand_tiny inline">N.H.</span></a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="http://www.pia.org/NJ"><span class="collapse_tiny">Carrier 3</span><span class="collapse expand_tiny inline">N.J.</span></a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="http://www.pia.org/NY"><span class="collapse_tiny">Carrier 4</span><span class="collapse expand_tiny inline">N.Y</span></a>

    </li>
</ul>
</div>
<br>
<br>
```

CSS:

```
 .state_box {
    margin-bottom:-9px;
    width:320px;
}
#state-tgl-label {
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-right:10px;
    padding-bottom:7px;
    padding-top:15px;
    background-color:rgba(6, 0, 0, 0.09);
}
.state_box ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style-type: none;
}
.state_box ul li {
    display:inline;
}
.state_box ul ul {
    display:inline;
}
.state_box ul li a {
    text-decoration:none;
    padding-left:16px;
    color:#000;
    font-family:'Raleway', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight:500;
    font-size:23px;
    font-size:2.3rem;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    vertical-align:-8px;
    color:#939598;
}
.state_box ul li a.first_state {
    padding-left:0px;
}
.state_box ul li .third_level {
    color:#a7a9ac;
    font-size:18px;
    font-size:1.8rem;
    vertical-align:-5px;
}
.state_box ul li .fourth_level {
    color:#BCBEC0;
    font-size:14px;
    font-size:1.4rem;
    vertical-align:-3px;
}
.state_box ul li a:hover {
    color:#808285;
}
.state_box ul li .selected_state {
    font-size:36px;
    font-size:3.6rem color:#000000;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    vertical-align:text-top;
    color:#000;
    font-family:'Raleway', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
#state-tgl {
    position:absolute;
    /* IE 8 */
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
    /* Real Browsers */
    opacity:0;
}
#state-tgl-label {
    font-size:28px;
    font-size:1.8rem;
    color:#000000;
    font-family:'Raleway', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    /*font-weight:500;*/
    display:block;
}
#state-tgl-label img {
    float:right;
    margin-top:5px;
}
#state_drop-menu {
    position:relative;
    z-index:9999;
    background-color:rgba(6, 0, 0, 0.09);
    /*border:solid 2px black;*/
    width:320px;
    padding-top:8px;
    padding-bottom:8px;
    display:none;
    max-height:0px;
    transition: max-height 0.25s ease;
    margin-top:10px;
}
#state_drop-menu li {
    display:block;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    width:100%;
}
#state_drop-menu li a {
    font-size:36px;
    font-size:1.8rem;
    color:black;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    display:block;
    padding-left:8px;
    padding-right:8px;
}
#state_drop-menu li a:hover {
    color:white;
    background-color:black;
}
#state-tgl:checked ~ #state_drop-menu {
    display:block;
    max-height:1000px;
}
/*########### Carrier Drop Menu ############*/
 .carrier_box {
    margin-bottom:-9px;
    width:320px;
}
.carrier_box ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style-type: none;
}
.carrier_box ul li {
    display:inline;
}
.carrier_box ul ul {
    display:inline;
}
.carrier_box ul li a {
    text-decoration:none;
    padding-left:16px;
    color:#000;
    font-family:'Raleway', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight:500;
    font-size:23px;
    font-size:2.3rem;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    vertical-align:-8px;
    color:#939598;
}
.carrier_box ul li a.first_carrier {
    padding-left:0px;
}
.carrier_box ul li .third_level {
    color:#a7a9ac;
    font-size:18px;
    font-size:1.8rem;
    vertical-align:-5px;
}
.carrier_box ul li .fourth_level {
    color:#BCBEC0;
    font-size:14px;
    font-size:1.4rem;
    vertical-align:-3px;
}
.carrier_box ul li a:hover {
    color:#808285;
}
.carrier_box ul li .selected_carrier {
    font-size:36px;
    font-size:3.6rem color:#000000;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    vertical-align:text-top;
    color:#000;
    font-family:'Raleway', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
#carrier-tgl {
    position:absolute;
    /* IE 8 */
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
    /* Real Browsers */
    opacity:0;
}
#carrier-tgl-label {
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-right:10px;
    padding-bottom:7px;
    padding-top:15px;
    background-color:rgba(6, 0, 0, 0.09);
    font-size:28px;
    font-size:1.8rem;
    color:#000000;
    font-family:'Raleway', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    /*font-weight:500;*/
    display:block;
}
#carrier-tgl-label img {
    float:right;
    margin-top:5px;
}
#carrier_drop-menu {
    position:relative;
    z-index:9999;
    background-color:rgba(6, 0, 0, 0.09);
    /*border:solid 2px black;*/
    width:320px;
    padding-top:8px;
    padding-bottom:8px;
    display:none;
    max-height:0px;
    transition: max-height 0.25s ease;
    margin-top:10px;
}
    #carrier_drop-menu li {
    display:block;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    width:100%;
    }
    #carrier_drop-menu li a {
    font-size:36px;
    font-size:1.8rem;
    color:black;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    display:block;
    padding-left:8px;
    padding-right:8px;
    }
    #carrier_drop-menu li a:hover {
    color:white;
    background-color:black;
    }
    #carrier-tgl:checked ~ #carrier_drop-menu {
    display:block;
    max-height:1000px;
    }
    #charts {
    margin-top:50px;
    }
```

JQuery:

```
/* 
$(document).click(function(){
  $(".state-menu").hide();
});

$(".state_box").click(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
});*/

$(".state_box").click(function(){
    $(".state-menu").show(1);
$(document).click(function(){
  $(".state-menu").hide();

});
});

/*function myFunction() {
    $(document).click(function () {
        $(".state-menu").hide(1);
    });
}*/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is not a very good solution - but this is based on the current structure of your html (as in jsFiddle) and my understanding of what you are trying to do...

```
$(".state_box").click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#carrier_drop-menu").hide();
    $('#state-tgl').prop('checked', true);
    $(".state-menu").show();
});
$(".carrier_box").click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".state-menu").hide();
    $('#carrier-tgl').prop('checked', true);
    $("#carrier_drop-menu").show();
});

$(document).click(function () {
    $(".state-menu").hide();
    $("#carrier_drop-menu").hide();
    $('#state-tgl').prop('checked', false);
    $('#carrier-tgl').prop('checked', false);
});
```

See [jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/taleebanwar/rc7fhhhu/7/)

---

**Edit** Based on comments - the code is updated to:

```
/*As initially the menus are hidden using css class
So toggle won't work for the first time.
So we need to add these two lines*/
$("#carrier_drop-menu").hide();
$(".state-menu").hide();

$(".state_box").click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#carrier_drop-menu").hide();
    $('#state-tgl').prop('checked', true);
    $(".state-menu").toggle();
});
$(".carrier_box").click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".state-menu").hide();
    $('#carrier-tgl').prop('checked', true);
    $("#carrier_drop-menu").toggle();
});

$(document).click(function () {
    $(".state-menu").hide();
    $("#carrier_drop-menu").hide();
    $('#state-tgl').prop('checked', false);
    $('#carrier-tgl').prop('checked', false);
});
```

Updated [JsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/taleebanwar/rc7fhhhu/10/).

Comment: Hey Thanks! This is exactly what I'm looking for. However, the menu no longer close when you click on the parent or the "state_box" and "Carrier_box"

Comment: Ah! you mean when state box is clicked again --- I did not think of that... Let me see

Comment: @StevenSerrano. See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/taleebanwar/rc7fhhhu/8/). I think there is one more issue - which I need to fix before I edit the answer.

Comment: @StevenSerrano. The jsFiddle I provided above - on first click the dropdown menu was not opening. I've fixed that and have edited my answer..

Comment: It seems it works only on the second click to the parent once the document loads, first click does nothing, then after that it works perfectly.

Comment: Already fixed that... See my edited answer. Also see Pot-Nut's answer. That looks like a better way to do this

Comment: Oh yes thank you!  I was too slow on my reply lol. It works perfectly. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: So I'm realizing that my links will no longer fire!! Is it because of the "checked, false"?

Comment: Awesome! So I realized the prevent default was causing the links not to fire, but could you explain how those e.stopPropagation(); did the trick?

Comment: Suppose there is a button inside a div. If we have clicks event for both button and div - when we click the button first button's event is called then div. This is called event bubbling. e.StopPropagation() stops the bubbling of events. So in your case on clicking `.state-menu` both the `.state-menu` and `document` event were triggering. We stopped that!

Answer (score 2):

Edited answer based on OPs comments below:

Working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/am83oczu/

Add a specific ID to each dropdown menu (example below uses `id="state-dropdown"` and `id="carrier-dropdown"`).

You also need to remove the `<input type="checkbox">` you have in place as its `onblur` attribute messes with everything.

```
$(document).on('click', function (event) {

    // Show the states dropdown if this was clicked...
    if (document.getElementById('state-tgl-label') === event.target ||
        $.contains(document.getElementById('state-tgl-label'), event.target)) {
            $('#carrier-dropdown').hide();
            if ($('#state-dropdown').is(':visible')) {
                $('#state-dropdown').hide();
            } else {
                $('#state-dropdown').show(1);
            }
    }

    // ... or show the carrier dropdown if this was clicked
    if (document.getElementById('carrier-tgl-label') === event.target ||
        $.contains(document.getElementById('carrier-tgl-label'), event.target)) {
            $('#state-dropdown').hide();
            if ($('#carrier-dropdown').is(':visible')) {
                $('#carrier-dropdown').hide();
            } else {
                $('#carrier-dropdown').show(1);
            }
    }

});
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, but this Is only showing and hiding the menus when a user clicks on them specifically, which is not my problem. They open/close fine when you click them directly.

Comment: Your problem is the mixture of detecting clicks on `document` and on the menus themselves. The reason it sometimes works and sometimes doesn't is to do with `bubbling` (sometimes it is only acting on your `document` click, sometimes it is only acting on your menu click). I'll edit my answer with an alternative solution for this.

Comment: @StevenSerrano I have updated my answer as promised - let me know if this helps: http://jsfiddle.net/e3jtgof4/

Comment: @StevenSerrano Additional change added to hide menus when already opened; new fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/am83oczu/

Comment: This was giving me wacky results. But thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @StevenSerrano As long as you remove the `<input type="checkbox">` with its `onblur` attribute it should work fine. Not sure why that input is there in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

Let's try by using this method here http://www.designchemical.com/blog/index.php/jquery/jquery-simple-vertical-accordion-menu/
You should manage to do what you want by following accordion menu tuto.